# Facing "IllegalLocationConstraintException" error

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to create a s3-bucket using AWS SDK for Python in PyCharm and facing the following error.

> "An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to."

Here is my code:

```
import os

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
SECRET_KEY = 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
PRI_BUCKET_NAME = 'soundcloud2'
TRANSIENT_BUCKET_NAME = 'soundcloud3'


def main():
    """entry point"""
    access = os.getenv(ACCESS_KEY)
    secret = os.getenv(SECRET_KEY)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=access, aws_secret_access_key=secret)

    create_bucket(TRANSIENT_BUCKET_NAME, s3)


def create_bucket(name, s3):
    try:
        bucket = s3.create_bucket(Bucket=name)
    except ClientError as ce:
        print('error', ce)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying your code as below:

```
bucket = s3.create_bucket(Bucket=name,
                                  CreateBucketConfiguration={
                                      'LocationConstraint': 'ap-south-1'}
                                  )
```

or whatever region, unless your region is in the U.S.